# Angular devextreme

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have a very large grid where the right hand side can only be viewed by scrolling to the right. When I want move a column to the left it will only go to the left limit of the scrolled view. Is there a way that scroll bar could automatically scroll to the left as we try and move the column to the left.
Thanks all

Comment: I guess there is, yes. When the question is just "is there any way to develop what I want?", I don't see how anybody could come up with an answer other than "Probably, yes".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question is not easy to answer with the lack of details.  I suggest you either create a reproducible code sample, include some code where you believe there is an issue, or generally provide more details about what it is you try to achieve.

Comment: i have a large grid i want to reordering column but this grid is limit of the scrolled view. I want to find a event support reordering column when i moving column. I use it to resold but this wrong
 contentReady(e) {
        var scrollable = e.component.getScrollable();
        console.log(scrollable.scrollLeft())
        scrollable.scrollTo({left: scrollable.scrollLeft() + 100, top: 0});
    }